# How to create an array of objects in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, regex, typescript, angular6

Below is my problem on creating array of objects using JavaScript. I am getting error message with new lines added as below where I need to split the messages and collect row numbers. The row numbers should be comma separated if it is repetitive error message.

I achieved through some ugly way and it is adding "undefined" string when I try concat the rows numbers.

Also, I might need solution optimized for large data. Most of the time I might get error messages between 3000 to 7000. I am using Angular 6 version.

My desired output is mentioned below.

```js
var errorMsg = `No address details found for record at row 3.
                No address details found for record at row 4.
                Invalid Street Number at row 5.
                Invalid Zip at row 6.
                Invalid Zip at row 7.
                Invalid Zip at row 11.`
var errorDisp = errorMsg.split(/^(.*)(\d.)/gm);

errorDisp = errorDisp.filter(function(entry) {
  return /\S/.test(entry);
});

var object = {};
var rows = [];
errorDisp.forEach(function(a, i, aa) {
  if (i & 1) {
    object[aa[i - 1]] += "," + a;
  }
});

console.log(object);
```

Output:

```
{
    "No address details found for record at row ": "undefined,3.,4.",
    "Invalid Street Number at row ": "undefined,5.",
    "Invalid Zip at row": "undefined,6.,7.,11."
}
```

Required output:

```
{
    "No address details found for record at row ": "3,4",
    "Invalid Street Number at row ": "5",
    "Invalid Zip at row": "6,7,11"
}
```

Comment: Do identical error messages always come next to each other, or may any line have any error message?

Comment: Yes, Identical error message always come but with different row numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `/\s*(.*?)(\d+).$/` to get the key and the value to separate capturing groups. Use [`exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) to loop through the matches and update the output object. If the key already exists, update it. Else add a new key to the object

```js
var errorMsg = `No address details found for record at row 3.
                No address details found for record at row 4.
                Invalid Street Number at row 5.
                Invalid Zip at row 6.
                Invalid Zip at row 7.
                Invalid Zip at row 11.`

let regex = /\s*(.*?)(\d+).$/gm,
    output = {},
    match;

while(match = regex.exec(errorMsg)) {
  const [,key, value] = match;
  if(output[key])
    output[key] += `,${value}`
  else
    output[key] = value
}

console.log(output)
```

Comment: I didn't know JS has a _hash_ construct `output = {}`

Comment: @sln that's just an empty [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Syntax)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a modified regex without the period:

```
var errorDisp = errorMsg.split(/^(.*)(\d+)\./gm);
```

Then, just make sure you check for `a` being falsy before adding it to the comma list:

```
if (a) object[aa[i - 1]] += "," + a;
```